# Batch Script for conversion of WAV files to MP3 automatically by traversing through sub-directories

Tags: batch-file, traversal, directory

### EDIT 1

STEP 1:
The telephonic conversations are recorded in .WAV format in specific folder and sub-folders (created **AUTOMATICALLY** by the the voice recording software in the current date format, i.e., **20121119 (YYYYMMDD)**. This naming convention cannot be changed. Current date sub-folders are automatically created in **D Drive** in the folder called **RECFILED**. Say, if the recordings are for today, the files would be stored in **20121119** sub-folder. Yesterday's files were stored in **20121118**.

STEP 2:
At the end of the day, these *.WAV files needs to be converted to *.MP3 format and to be uploaded to Amazon S3. At present this process is manual. Since, there are lot many WAV files, so I use SOX to batch convert the WAV to MP3. For this purpose, I have created a batch file (explained in my original question) so that this conversion process can be automated. This batch file converts the WAV to MP3 and saves the MP3 files in same folder as of the WAV files. For this, what I have to do is to copy the batch file in the folder and run it. It converts the files and save it in the same folder.

STEP 3: Once the files are converted. Then on Amazon S3, in a specific bucket, I have to create a new folder with current date so that all these MP3's can be stored there. **BUT, the date format here is DD.MM.YYYY**. The folder hierarchy is **\BucketName\Voice\201211\19.11.2012\*.MP3 (for today)**, **\BucketName\Voice\201211\20.11.2012\*.MP3 (for tomorrow)** and so on.

Now, the problem is:

1. Traverse to the latest folder (looking in to d:\RecFileD\YYYYMMDD) and see if there are WAV files available in the folder. If yes, the convert these files to MP3 and store them in the folder called DD.MM.YYYY on local server on any specific location. (today's date but with a different format).
2. Once, the folder is created (with DD.MM.YYYY naming convention. The same folders needs to be uploaded on S3 in a specific month (i.e., 201211). And once the month changes, say December, the files related to December month would go in the folder 201212 and so on.
3. The problem here is that on local server the naming convention is YYYYMMDD (without spaces, dot or comma) and on S3 the naming convention is DD.MM.YYYY (with dots).

### ORIGINAL QUESTION

Please help me write a batch file so that I can automate the process of conversion of WAV files to MP3 and then uploading them directly to Amazon S3 to specific folders. Right now it is a manual process.

Actually, we are running a small call centre and all the voice calls are recorded and saved on the server in `D:` drive in folder named `RecFileD` and sub-folders named with the current date (i.e., `20121117`, `20121116` and so on). The files are saved in WAV format by default. I need to convert the files to MP3 before uploading them to Amazon S3 for storage.

The requirement is that I need to upload the MP3 files daily on the S3 on a specific time at the end of the day. The problem is how to traverse to the last folder (current date folder) and convert the files. On local server the voice files are saved in `d:\RecFileD\20121117\*.wav` and on Amazon S3 the files are uploaded in folders:

- `\BucketName\Voice\201211\17.11.2012\*.mp3` (this is for November month);
- `\bucketName\Voice\201212\01.12.2012\*.mp3` (this would be for Dec month) (31 folders for all days).

To automate the conversion, I have created the below batch file. This file uses the SOX application to convert the WAV files to MP3 in the current folder.

```
@echo off
call :treeprocess
goto :eof

:treeprocess
for %%f in (*.wav) do 
(
  sox %%~nf.WAV %%~nf.mp3
  sox %%~nf.WAV %%~nf-short.mp3 trim 0:30 1:00
)

for /D %%d in (*) do 
(
  cd %%d
  call :treeprocess
  cd ..
)
exit /b
```

To automate the uploading of files to S3, I'd be using S3 command line tool.

In brief, following steps are required:

1. Traverse to the current date folder only (`20121115`, `20121116`, `20121117` etc.) on local server and convert the WAV files to MP3 (using the above script).
2. Move those MP3 files to the separate folder created automatically named as `17.11.2012` (as per current date).
3. Upload the folder to Amazon S3 on specific location. i.e., `\bucketname\voice\201211\17.11.2012`.

Comment: what is the problem you have?

Comment: Your question seems rather complex at the moment. Generally, it is preferable when a question deals with one specific problem. That way it is easier to make an answer clear and universal, for the benefit of many people who may later come across the question. And I think it should be possible to split yours into two or three more specific questions. For instance, "How to traverse directories in batch files?", "How to format current date as '...' in batch files?" etc. Note that some of these specific questions may have already been answered. So please consider searching this site before asking.

Comment: You basically give a description of what your software should do and ask for someone to tell you how to do it ... Sorry, but I think that's not what SO is about.

Comment: You give an example path to the source .wav files. You describe some naming conventions for the generated .mp3 files both local and remote. Please give a specific example .mp3 path (full local path and the remote path on S3). Also please show what S3 command you are using with an example of it's usage. Once the files are uploaded, do you keep a local copy (I think you should, if possible). How can you tell if a date has been processed? What would happen if processing skipped / failed one day? How would you notice, recover and process the missing day?

Comment: Added 'latest' filter to my second solution to "Traverse to the latest folder".

Comment: Added text to my solution describing how the dest paths are generated. Previously I only described splitting up the source dir name.

Comment: Do you have a workable solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is pretty good, you're pretty close.

The environment I was testing on required `do (` to have the open paren on the same line as the do. Your formatting with a newline in the middle may be causing a problem.

What you're totally missing is any parsing of the directory name which is expected to be YYYYMMDD. You can do that with:

```
set dirname=%%d

set year=%dirname:~0,4%
set month=%dirname:~4,2%
set day=%dirname:~6,2%
```

Once your done this it's easy to create file names and paths based on YYYY, MM, DD:

```
set s3path=!file_year!!file_month!\!file_day!.!file_month!.!file_year!
```

will generate a path like YYYYMM\DD.MM.YYYY.

You can get the 'last' dir using:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%a IN ('dir /b /a:d /o:n ????????') do (
  set dirset=%%a
)
```

Note: this is only implemented in the second solution. Let's break this down:

```
dir /b /a:d /o:n ????????
```

Does a directory in 'bare' format (just the list of matching files, one per line), with attribute directory (only list directories), orders by name (this is the default on NTFS but not on FAT so best to specify sort order), matching ????????, any 8 characters (because the directories are expected to be named like YYYYMMDD so always 8 characters). This returns an ordered list of 8 character directory names.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%a IN ('command') do echo %%a
```

Executes the `command` and parses the results, line by line. Here the first token of each result will be echoed.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%a IN ('dir /b /a:d /o:n ????????') do (
  set dirset=%%a
)
```

We put it all together and see that `dirset` will be set to each matching directory name. But after the `for` loop finishes it will be left set to the *last* value, or 'latest' directory.

In the code below I have `dirname` set separately to avoid problems with variable expansion rules. Alternatively, you should be able to use:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 

set dirname=%%d
set year=!dirname:~0,4!
```

You problem, as stated, does not require recursion. My code just iterates each dir, then iterates each file. If the file layout is less structured then you indicate, then recursion may be needed.

You didn't specify which Windows S3 command line tool you use so I echo `*S3COPY*` with local full path and partial path. You should be able to replace this with your copy command.

You'll need to run this from `d:\RecFileD` or you could add this near the top of the bat file:

```
d:
cd \RecFileD
```

You'll probably need to change `s3root` to the actual root dir of your local S3 copy. Instead of moving the files, I have sox create them in the correct location.

I set year, month, day vars in `processfiles` because setting them in `processdirs` is complicated by variable expansion rules.

If you're doing much more than this, I'd recommend looking into Python. It's got a great community / eco-system, is easy to get started with and is free. Plus you don't wind up spending all your time fighting with the language.

Here's my first try:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set s3root=d:\s3\bucket\voice

call :processdirs
goto :eof

:processfiles
  set year=%dirname:~0,4%
  set month=%dirname:~4,2%
  set day=%dirname:~6,2%

  set s3path=%year%%month%\%day%.%month%.%year%
  set s3dir=%s3root%\%s3path%
  if not exist "%s3dir%" md "%s3dir%"

  for %%f in (*.wav) do (
    sox "%%~nf.WAV" "%s3dir%\%%~nf.mp3"
    sox "%%~nf.WAV" "%s3dir%\%%~nf-short.mp3" trim 0:30 1:00
  )

  echo *S3COPY* %s3dir% %s3path%
  goto :eof

:processdirs
  for /D %%d in (*) do (
    set dirname=%%d
    cd "%%d"
    call :processfiles
    cd ..
  )
  goto :eof
```

@Aacini answer made me realize, unfortunately my solution is lacking. It doesn't process only today's files. But I'm concerned with what happens when a day is skipped.

I added two parameters to control what is processed. The first parameter specifies a named filter and can be one of:

- **newlatest** - new files in latest directory, based on filename (default)
- **latest** - all files in latest directory, based on filename
- **today** - today's directory
- **newdirs** - all dirs (missing dates) that don't exist in the S3 tree
- **newfiles** - all files that don't exist in the S3 tree
- **all** - all files (used to overwrite corruption in S3 tree)

If the filter is `newdirs`, `newfiles` or `all`, then a second parameter can be used to further filter on directory name. You can use the * and ? wildcard characters to match a set of files.

If you save the script as ProcDirs.bat then here are some examples:

`ProcDirs all 20121119`
Will force the processing (or reprocessing) of the specified dir.

`ProcDirs newdirs 201211??`
Will process new directories (missing from output tree) that match the dir name (any day of the specified year and month).

`ProcDirs newfiles 2012????`
Will process new files (missing from output tree) in directories that match the dir name (any day of the specified year).

`ProcDirs`
`ProcDirs newlatest`
Are the exact same because `newlatest` is the default. This will process new files in the (lexically) 'latest' directory

The code is more complicated, but not *too bad*. I did try to use @Aacini's code to get today's month/day/year but it didn't work on my system (because my date format must be different than required). So I'm using a different approach that doesn't depend on local date formats.

My first solution didn't require delayed expansion but this one does so I turn it on with `setlocal` (works on Win XP but maybe not older Windows) and use `!` instead of `%` for environment variable substitution.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set s3root=d:\s3\bucket\voice

rem Set the default filter mode

set newfilter=none
set dirsetfilter=none

set arg=%1
if "!arg!" == "" set arg=newlatest

if "!arg!" == "newdirs" (
  set newfilter=newdirs
) else if "!arg!" == "newfiles" (
  set newfilter=newfiles
) else if "!arg!" == "all" (
  set dirsetfilter=none
  set newfilter=none
) else if "!arg!" == "today" (
  set dirsetfilter=today
) else if "!arg!" == "latest" (
  set dirsetfilter=latest
) else if "!arg!" == "newlatest" (
  set newfilter=newfiles
  set dirsetfilter=latest
)

if !dirsetfilter! == today (
  for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%a IN ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year /Format:table') do (
    if %%a GTR 0 (
      set now_day=%%a
      set now_month=%%b
      set now_year=%%c
    )
  )
  set dirset=!now_year!!now_month!!now_day!
  if not "%2" == "" echo Second parameter, dirset, ignored when filter is today
) else if !dirsetfilter! == latest (
  rem pull out the name of the 'last' directory
  for /f "tokens=1" %%a IN ('dir /b /a:d /o:n ????????') do (
    set dirset=%%a
  )
  if not "%2" == "" echo Second parameter, dirset, ignored when filter is latest
) else if not "%2" == "" (
  rem The second parameter is dirset. Wild card chars, *? allowed
  rem only matched dir(s) processed
  set dirset=%2
) else (
  rem process all dirs that match filter
  set dirset=*
)

call :processdirs
goto :eof

:processfiles
  set file_year=!dirname:~0,4!
  set file_month=!dirname:~4,2!
  set file_day=!dirname:~6,2!

  set s3path=!file_year!!file_month!\!file_day!.!file_month!.!file_year!
  set s3dir=!s3root!\!s3path!

  set skipdir=FALSE
  if not exist "!s3dir!" (
    md "!s3dir!"
  ) else (
    if newdirs == !newfilter! set skipdir=TRUE
  )

  if !skipdir! == FALSE (
    set havenewfiles=FALSE

    for %%f in (*.wav) do (
      set skipfile=FALSE
      if newfiles==!newfilter! if exist "!s3dir!\%%~nf.mp3" set skipfile=TRUE
      if !skipfile! == FALSE (
        set havenewfiles=TRUE
        echo sox "%%~nf.WAV" "!s3dir!\%%~nf.mp3"
        sox "%%~nf.WAV" "!s3dir!\%%~nf.mp3"
      )

      set skipfile=FALSE
      if newfiles == !newfilter! if exist "!s3dir!\%%~nf-short.mp3" set skipfile=TRUE
      if !skipfile! == FALSE (
        set havenewfiles=TRUE
        echo sox "%%~nf.WAV" "!s3dir!\%%~nf-short.mp3" trim 0:30 1:00
        sox "%%~nf.WAV" "!s3dir!\%%~nf-short.mp3" trim 0:30 1:00
      )
    )

    if !havenewfiles! == TRUE (
      echo *S3COPY* !s3dir! !s3path!
    )
  )
  goto :eof

:processdirs
  for /D %%d in (!dirset!) do (
    echo Process Dir: %%d
    set dirname=%%d
    cd "%%d"
    call :processfiles
    cd ..
  )
  goto :eof
```

Good luck. I hope this helps.

Comment: Well I missed your first point re only today's date. My code assumes you move the processed files at some point. @Aacini properly handles just today's files. As for your second point, moving files, I've had better luck with generating the files in place in order to skip moving. It's one less step and less possible states if the process crashes midway (can't crash during move). My code never needs to move the files.

Comment: Also think about problems in production. If you job doesn't run one day or crashes, make sure it's not too hard to process previous day's files.

Comment: I've posted a major update with a second version where you get to select what get's processed: today's files, new dirs, new files, or all files. Unfortunately it's more complicated.

Comment: Hey jimhark: Thank you so much for quick revert. Let me try this in my scenario. Will surely update you on this.

Comment: Added a second parameter to allow additional filtering on directory name.

Comment: Added explanation of code that figures out 'latest' directory.